# Some questions about generic points and regular points on a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

Recently, I've been reading [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-004-1202-0) about Brauer groups. I am not sophisticated with algebraic geometry, and got some confusions about the proof of lemma 3. These questions may be naive for experts. But I still thank to any commentary. Let me cite the Lemma 3 and part of the proof in the paper as following:

> Let $X$ be a separated noetherian scheme and $U$ an open subscheme of
>   $X$. Assume that $U$ contains every generic point and every singular
>   point of $X$. Then the restriction homomorphism
>   $$H^2(X,\mathbb{G}_m)\rightarrow H^2(U,\mathbb{G}_m)$$ is injective.

Let $i:U\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion and let $X^{(1)}$ be the set of points of codimension $1$ in $X$. $\forall x\in X$, let $i_{x*}: Spec(k(x))\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion of $x$ in $X$. Let $V \rightarrow X$ be any etale morphism and $W=V\times_XU$. Here are my confusions:

1. Why any generic point $\eta \in V$ maps to a generic point $\xi  \in X$ ?
2. Why every $y\in V^{(1)}\backslash W$ lies over some $x\in X^{(1)}\backslash U$ ? (i.e., the existence of $x$)

By assumption, $x$ is regular. Thus $y$ is regular on $V$. Then

3. Why a regular point $y\in V^{(1)}\backslash W$ defines a discrete rank $1$ valuation $v_y: \mathbb{G}_m(W)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ ?

It seems that after getting the discrete valuation $v_y$ we have the sheaf morphism $$\varphi : i_{*}\mathbb{G}_{m} \rightarrow \bigoplus _{x \in X^{(1)} \backslash U}i_{x*}\mathbb{Z}$$ and the last question is

4. How to get $\varphi$ ? By the way, what does the symbol $i_{x*}\mathbb{Z}$'s meaning?